# Angular (2) material autocomplete custom filter

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material-6

Thanks for your help in advance.

So currently I am filtering a list of search results based off a string value so for example I have an ngFor that gets a list of strings like "product name 1", "product name 2", etc. It filters through the list of items without an issues and splices only the values we typed in. But what I need to do is filter out those names based off a string of keywords.

So for example "product name 1" is the name and it's keywords are "product one prod active directory help desk" if the keywords contain any part of the string then I have to display only the product name, in this example "product name 1" based off of those keywords. (Hopefully that makes sense, code below)

Currently the list is filtered based off of if the string matches something so for example if I start typing in "prod" everything starting with "prod" will appear. But what I need to do instead is based it off if a string contains that text so for example let's say we start typing in "prod" again .... and in my array I have a string that says "product 1 active directory etc" i want it to find it by that but it also has to work if I type active directory

products.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    // proudct is an input field shown below
      this.filteredProducts = this._form1.controls['product'].valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | Product>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.products.slice())
      );

  }

  // Display the result in the dropdown list
  displayFn(product?: Product): string | undefined {
    return product ? product.name : undefined;
  }

  // Filter through the list of items
  private _filter(name: string): Product[] {
    if(name) {

      const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

      return this.products.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
    }
  }
```

product.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="_form1" (ngSubmit)="_onFirstSubmit()" class="step-container">

    <mat-form-field class="mat-full-width-container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Product or service name" aria-label="product" matInput formControlName="product" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (input)="prodChanged()" (blur)="selectProduct()">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts | async" [value]="product">
          {{ product.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

Please help I've tried a couple of things can't seem to get it, thanks

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Currently the list is filtered based off of if the string matches something so for example if I start typing in "prod" everything starting with "prod" will appear. But what I need to do instead is based it off if a string contains that text so for example let's say we start typing in "prod" again .... and in my array I have a string that says "product 1 active directory etc" i want it to find it by that but it also has to work if I type active directory

Comment: Let me know what specifically you need to know that's the best I can explain it

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line like this :

```
return this.products.filter(option => 
 option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) >= 0);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I don't why I didn't realize that earlier, I appreciate your help and I'll accept this as the answer.